# RuntimeError: cannot access configuration outside request

Tags: python, flask

I got following error:

```
RuntimeError: cannot access configuration outside request
```

from executing following code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flaskext.uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, patch_request_class

app = Flask(__name__)
csvfiles = UploadSet('csvfiles', 'csv', "/var/uploads")

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello World!"

@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'csvfile' in request.files:
        filename = csvfiles.save(request.files['csvfile']) # the error occurs here!
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('upload.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I don't understand the error message itself and i don't know how to solve the problem.
I read the official documentation, and it seems i have to do some configuration (where to store the uploads), but i don't know how to do it the right way.

I'm using the [Flask-Uploads](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Uploads/) extension.

This is running in a python 2.7 virtual environment with the following installed packages:

```
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Uploads==0.1.3
Jinja2==2.7.2
MarkupSafe==0.23
Werkzeug==0.9.4
argparse==1.2.1
itsdangerous==0.24
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You haven't [configured the Flask-Uploads extension](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Uploads/#app-configuration). Use the [`configure_uploads()` function](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Uploads/#flaskext.uploads.configure_uploads) to attach your upload sets to your app:

```
from flaskext.uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOADED_CSVFILES_DEST'] = '/var/uploads'
csvfiles = UploadSet('csvfiles', ('csv',))
configure_uploads(app, (csvfiles,))
```

The second argument to `UploadSet()` takes a *sequence* of extensions. Don't pass in the file path to an `UploadSet`; you would use your [Flask configuration](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config/) instead.

Set `UPLOADED_<name-of-your-set>_DEST`, where the name is uppercased. Here that's `UPLOADED_CSVFILES_DEST`. You can also set a `UPLOADS_DEFAULT_DEST` configuration; it'll be used as a base directory, with separate subdirectories for each set name.

Alternatively, that 3rd parameter can be a callable:

```
configure_uploads(app, (csvfiles,), lambda app: '/var/uploads')
```

Comment: that's right. But then it says "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" because 3rd parameter of UploadSet has to be a callable.. okay.. but i do not really need to store the files at all! I just want to upload and process them... so when i remove the 3rd param i got the error: "RuntimeError: no destination for set csvfiles
" .. this is tricky :/

Comment: @tector: right, that's because you should be using flask configuration, not a 3rd argument.

Comment: hm.. so i have to set: app.config['UPLOADED_FILES_DEST'] = '/var/uploads' ? that doesn't work..

Comment: @tector: No, you need to set `UPLOADED_<name-of-the-set-in-uppercase>_DEST`.

Comment: @tector: the documentation does explain this. :-) My answer sets `UPLOADED_CSVFILES_DEST`, for example.

Comment: Ok, now i understand and it works! Thanks! I saw your edited answer just one second after my response. However: The documentation covers this issue - but it is not very obvious for a flask beginner and can be improved!